# Multithreading Scrape Html and Safely Save to One File

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I want scrape the title from given url in multiple thread (example in 5 thread)
and save them to one text file. how to do it and how to make sure I safely save the output to one file?

this is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

urls = []

with open('Input.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        urls.append(row[1])

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

def get_title( url ):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        html_content = r.text.encode('UTF-8')
        title = find_between(html_content , "<title>", "</title>")
        return title
    except:
        return ""

for url in urls:
    f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write(get_title(url) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: I would either use asyncio but if you are in the python3 world you can use future or multiprocess again I am too lazy to write it for you it is a lot of work hahaha

Answer (score 1):

try to use futures
1. create pool
2. sumbit function and parameters
3. get result from function

```
import csv
from concurrent import futures
pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
workers = [pool.sumbit(get_title,url) for url in urls]
while not all(worker.done() for worker in workers):
   pass
with open(file) as f:
   w = csv.writer(f)
   w.writerows([[worker.result()] for worker in workers])
```

Comment: with your script, it will save to file after all worker done. 

how we can save it without waiting after worker done?

Comment: @TutikMasfiyah that is harder, you need a lock.